# Delphi 2010 - hide welcome page

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

Does anybody know how can i disable welcome page without using the < -np > command line option, its very the annoying and blocks the IDE for a few seconds on each start, does anybody know where can i configure this?

Comment: What's wrong with including the `-np` command linke option in the shortcut you're using to start Delphi?

Comment: @Cosmin: nothing wrong on that, but we have huge application which includes alot of projects which we open usually by clicking the dproj file, so i dont want be forced to run delphi over the shortcut each time i want to open a project.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund - thanks, great tip for me. I finally disposed that troublesome screen at start through the shortcut (but still the traditional MS paperclip is worse than this :)

Comment: Personally, i'd leave "Welcome Page" package in peace, but amend association to start w/o it when project to open is known

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can disable it in the registry: under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Known IDE Packages`, find the entry named `$(BDS)\Bin\startpageide140.bpl` and modify the value by prepending an underscore (so it looks like `'_Borland Start Page IDE Package'`). You can re-enable it later by removing the underscore.

Comment: That's the closest answer, see http://support.embarcadero.com/article/36854. I would say, this would work for the versions since the mentioned D2006 till now. It takes me about 3 seconds on the net, well, we have a slow connection somehow for now :)

Comment: I didn't know about this underscored hack. However i'd better move value outside of the key.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you delete it or rename. The only thing what Delphi checks is if exists name value pair $(BDS)\Bin\startpageideXXX.bpl=Start Page IDE Package, where XXX is your library version. If not, it doesn't display the welcome page.

Comment: @daemon_x: the value can be any string (it serves as a description to be displayed in the Installed packages dialog and by default comes from the package's description set in its project options) but as long as it's prefixed with an underscore the IDE will ignore it. Other ways to disable a package from the IDE include deleting the registry value altogether, renaming it to a value which doesn't resolve to an existing .bpl file name, or renaming the .bpl file. The underscore prefix is simply the easiest to revert.

Comment: @daemon_x, name-value pair? Not really. Format is `<filename> "=" <display-name>`. Obviously, messing with filenames breaks a things. In contrary, editing display names is much less crude way to change behaviour in question.

Comment: @Worm Regards - yep, e.g. in Czech Windows is this called as "name" and "value" in the registry

Comment: @daemon_x, yeah, kinda ambiguous, key has values and its values are... oh, dear... Anyway, "official" key for disabled packages is `Disabled IDE Packages`

Answer (score 4):

Easier, rename Bin\startpageideXXX.bpl and it won't ever show the welcome page again. Rename it back to reactivate. No registry needed.

Tested with latest Rad Studio XE as well.

Comment: easy and safe solution.+1

Comment: I did so, it is not coming back after you rename it back. Stuck with a blank screen for now.

Answer (score 2):

You already know the answer to this, use the `-np` command line option.  Simply change your file association for .dproj, .groupproj, .dpr etc. to include this option and it's all good!

Comment: actually i dont, otherwise i wouldnt ask! but if we are talking about it how can i change the association to work with a commandline parameter? and if its possible im not sure i would work as the -np refers to no project so i wouldnt expect it to work. I tried to associate the dpr with the shortcut i have with the -np but this  didnt work.

Comment: My point is that your question identifies the answer. I'd modify the file association by changing the registry.