# delphi 2010 and IE9

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, internet-explorer-9

I have recently installed IE9 and I think that is the reason why my delphi 2010 does not work anymore. Does anything this could be related. and how could i solve it. This is driving me nuts! It gives me an error: `out of stack space`. It doesn't lead to any help on the forums online. Since everything that is done there I can't seem to find or do such as deleting this file BDS.DSK. I am now using windows 7. with IE9 and delphi 2010

Hope you can help!!!

Comment: I have that problem too! Can't find the solution

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the Welcome Page which uses embedded IE browser control. Try [disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003275/embarcadero-d2010-hide-welcome-page) it.

Comment: this is the one! Thank you so much, you saved my computer from being cut into pieces!

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad it helped! However, I would also try jszpilewski's tip - if clearing the browser cache helps you could continue using the Welcome page.

Comment: yeah will if you figure that out, I am all ears! I have cleaned mine, just by doing it in tools. but its not made a difference

Answer (score 1):

Once in the past I had a similar problem with starting Delphi and clearing the IE cache helped.