# Skip welcome page in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embarcadero D2010 hide welcome page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003275/embarcadero-d2010-hide-welcome-page)

I have Delphi 2010. How do I skip the welcome page on startup and/or create a new project like Delphi 7?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as Delphi XE 2010. Either you got Delphi 2010, or you got Delphi XE.

Comment: @sertac, thanks. I searched but couldn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the package startpageide150.bpl from the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\Known IDE Packages`, and you will not get a welcome page.

But you will still need to click `File -> New -> Delphi VCL Forms application` to  create a new application each time the IDE starts up.

Because there is more than one type of project a user might need to start with, auto-creating one type isn't possible in the IDE any more.  Even if you are a delphi-only customer (no C++Builder in RAD Studio IDE), you still might want to open the IDE and open an existing project 99% of your typical working days.

Comment: Thanks Warren, precise and informative answer. Will do that. Kind of sad that I can't auto open projects anymore, but looks like I will have to get used to it. Thanks again

Comment: The welcome page contains your recently opened projects. So if you keep the welcome page you are only 1 click away from your last project.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I also kind of thought to rather keep the Welcome page, otherwise I anyway have to go to File > New Form. Where as with the welcome page, two clicks and I'm there. Plus I like the advanced features for previous projects

Comment: Even better feature on Welcome page, is Favorite projects, then even if I have opened 300 other projects, my main all-day work project is always in the Favorite list.

Comment: Yes, I saw that feature. Turns out that Welcome Page is useful afterall...

Comment: Actually, more right way(tm) is to move `startpageideNNN.bpl` from the `Known IDE Packages` to the `Disabled IDE Packages`