# Delphi 10.3 Rio - remove the welcome page

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there a way to get rid of that annoying welcome page when you start the IDE ?

With some former versions you could have done it through the registry but I can find it for Rio. Tried renaming the folder 'welcome page' to something else but then I get the error - page not found. Is there a way to avoid this and just simply get rid of it ?

Comment: The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345947/62576) may help. The numbers in the file name for Rio are 260.

Comment: In the bin folder of Delphi (typically C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin for Rio), rename startpageide260.bpl to something else

Comment: In case you have installed Delphi for "All Users", deleting the startpageide package in HKCU alone will not help. It will be restored from the HKLM entry with the next IDE start. You have to delete it also from HKLM to really get rid of it.

Comment: @Dave Nottage you can post the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually Dave's Nottage suggestion which works quite well without having to meddle with the registry. If he wants he can post the answer.
(In the bin folder of Delphi (typically C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin for Rio), rename startpageide260.bpl to something else – Dave Nottage ) Example :

[image]

Comment: Your answer is fine :-)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, because the latest spams from E********** are throwing tons of jQuery error messages during startup.

Answer (score 13):

Simple way of doing things :"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\bds.exe" -np -ns

-NP This removes  Welcome Page.
-NS This removes Starting screen.

Answer (score 8):

Putting an underscore in front of the package description stills works here.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Known IDE Packages
```

[image]

Ref: [The Wiert Corner - Delphi packages I have disabled by prefixing their description with an underscore (and why)](https://wiert.me/2016/07/19/delphi-packages-i-have-disabled-by-prefixing-their-description-with-an-underscore-and-why/)

Comment: for Rad Studio 11 this `$(BDS)\Bin\WelcomePageIDE280.bpl` = `Welcome Page IDE Package`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of remove it, you could edit the \Welcomepage\en\default.htm and \Welcomepage\css\styles_light.css files to show something more helpful. In mine, I removed the "Get Started", "Upcoming Events" and "YouTube Videos" panels, increased the size of favorites panel, and some other things.

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution is described in the picture. Applies to other versions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in answers, simply edit shortcut and add -np switch so it looks like following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\bds.exe" -pDelphi **-np**
```

You will no more have Welcome screen.