# Where are the config files from delphi Rad Studio located?

Tags: delphi, location, registry, config

I am searching for the config files from Delphi Rad Studio.

I found some entries in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero)
But changes I've made had no affect on Rad studio.
My inital goal was to clear the closed files of the editor, because I  don't want to see them everytime I open Rad studio.

Thank you!

I am using the version 'XE6'

Comment: Disable the welcome screen

Comment: Or modify your Reopen Menu to not remember projects or files. Either way, you shouldn't have to manually modify any config to do this.

Comment: Otherwise, is this what you were looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003275/delphi-2010-hide-welcome-page